# Laravel - Cron Jobs Duplicate error in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I write a cron job code in Laravel as shown below, but I sometimes get duplicate error in my log.

> Next Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'f984rfhnd' for key 'smskey' in /home/mms/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:143
>   Stack trace:

```
public function handle() {


    $array_content=[];

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.testing.com/article/feeddsdwst7?_fmt=json&_rt=b&ctg=english%20football%20sms&_fld=tsr,pt&kwd=arsenal");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); //Important
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
   // return $result;

    $array = json_decode($result, true);
    $category="arsenal";
    $title=$array['title'];
    $description=$array['description'];
    $asset_count=$array['assetCount'];
    $articles= $array['articles'];
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close ($ch);


   foreach( $articles as $art)
   {
        SmsFeed::create([
            'smskey'      =>  $art['id'],
            'category'     =>  $category,
             'asset_count'  =>   $asset_count,
            'title'     => $title,
            'description' =>$description,
            'published_time'    => $art['publishedTime'],
            'teaser'    => $art['teaser'],

        ]); 
   } 
}
```

smskey is a unique key. So I want it that if it exists, the operation should ignore and move to the next one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `Integrity constraint violation: 1062` error occur when given string size exceeds from the length of the corresponding column in database.

Can you please verify the size of the column of `smskey` in database

For skipping when duplicate occurs, you should whether if any duplicate entries exist or not.

```
foreach( $articles as $art)
   {
        $duplicate = SmsFeed::where('smskey',$art['id'])->count(); 
        if($duplicate == 0)
        {
            SmsFeed::create([
               'smskey'      =>  $art['id'],
               'category'     =>  $category,
               'asset_count'  =>   $asset_count,
               'title'     => $title,
               'description' =>$description,
               'published_time'    => $art['publishedTime'],
               'teaser'    => $art['teaser'],
            ]); 
        }
   }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `firstOrCreate` for this, it will get the first record matching the attributes or create it.

```php
foreach ($articles as $article) {
    SmsFeed::firstOrCreate(
        ['smskey' => $article['id']],
        [
            'category'       => $category,
            'asset_count'    => $asset_count,
            'title'          => $title,
            'description'    => $description,
            'published_time' => $article['publishedTime'],
            'teaser'         => $article['teaser'],
        ]
    );
}
```

[docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models)

```php
public function firstOrCreate(array $attributes, array $values = [])
```